# Trying to Reset column for every change in opponent

Tags: python, pandas

Have a Batting Order here and trying to reset it based on changing opponent

For example: When opponent changed from Colorado State to UTSA Batting Order needs to reset back to 1

```
df['Batting Order'] = df['pa'].cumsum().mod(9).apply(lambda x: 9 if x == 0 else x) 

                    pa  Batting Order        opponent
Abilene Christian 0    1              1  Colorado State
                1    1              2  Colorado State
                2    1              3  Colorado State
                3    1              4  Colorado State
                4    1              5  Colorado State
                5    1              6  Colorado State
                6    1              7  Colorado State
                7    1              8  Colorado State
                8    1              9  Colorado State
                9    1              1  Colorado State
                10   1              2  Colorado State
                11   1              3  Colorado State
                12   1              4  Colorado State
                13   1              5  Colorado State
                14   1              6  Colorado State
                15   1              7  Colorado State
                16   1              8  Colorado State
                17   1              9  Colorado State
                18   1              1  Colorado State
                19   1              2  Colorado State
                20   1              3  Colorado State
                21   0              3  Colorado State
                22   1              4  Colorado State
                23   1              5            UTSA
                24   1              6            UTSA
                25   1              7            UTSA
                26   0              7            UTSA
                27   1              8            UTSA
                28   1              9            UTSA
                29   1              1            UTSA
                30   0              1            UTSA
                31   1              2            UTSA
                32   0              2            UTSA
                33   1              3            UTSA
                34   0              3            UTSA
```

Comment: Hi Andreas Tan, could you please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: `df['Batting Order'] = df.groupby('Order').cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: @yatu : group by `'opponent'`

Comment: `df['Batting Order'] = df.groupby('opponent').cumcount() % 9 + 1`

Comment: Doesn't factor in 'pa', the batting order should stay the same if 'pa' = 0

Comment: Then use your code: `df.groupby('opponent')['pa'].cumsum().mod(9).apply(lambda x: 9 if x == 0 else x)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
def reset(df):
    grouping = df.groupby('Opponent')
    teams = grouping.groups.keys()
    batting_Order = []
    for team in teams:
        subset = grouping.get_group(team)
        for i in range(len(subset)):
            batting_Order.append(i)
    df['Batting Order'] = batting_Order
    return df
```